# custom directive for radio buttons in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

create the custom directive for radio buttons in angular js

i tried so far

HTML:

```
  <my-raido></my-raido>
  <my-raido></my-raido>
  <my-raido></my-raido>
```

Angular js:

```
var App = angular.module('myRaido',[]);

App.directive('myRaido',function() {

    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        template:  '<div class="myClass"><input type="radio"></div>',
        replace:true,
        link:function (scope, element, attrs) {

            element.click(function () {
                console.log("clicked....");
                // body...
            });

            console.log("link should be work as per our expections...", + attrs.valve);
        }
    }
});
```

Advance Thanks

Comment: functionlity is not working properly @maddog

Comment: it would be better if you could point to an error or let us know what is happening in console or anywhere.

Comment: Hi @maddog, In Template i am taken 3 custom directives (<my-raido></my-raido>), but only one radio button should select right, if suppose one button select reaming two shouldn't selected, but here 3 buttons selected. that is my problem

Comment: every directive has its own scope. i did not get how code achieved the thing you are asking for. 
I tried a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/YaUTQOHrPudybd69id8P?p=preview
Some other error there, i believe.

Comment: Hi @maddog, here where is the radio buttons, i will share my plunker.

Comment: I noticed you are using the directive to just generate radio buttons from the comments above you want the buttons to be linked. If that is the case you need to make the input field of the radio in the template have the same name as each other. So try setting a name attribute in the template radio.

Comment: 3 radio buttons are mutually exclusive if they have the same name. That's not the case here.

Comment: @Geohut i have used different names. but i am not sure why i m not able to see the radio buttons.

Comment: If you read the OP comment above that is their issue they want only one selected. As it is now all of them get selected. @JBNizet

Comment: Oh ok you can't even get them to display at all.

Comment: @Geohut yes, that's why I'm saying that the three radio buttons should have the same name. Otherwise, each of them can be selected independantly of the others.

Comment: Hi @maddog, Please visit my Plunker : [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L5m1qbjwiLghcruVgflx?p=preview)

Comment: @JBNizet it's ok you just responded right after me thought you were disputing it.

Comment: Hi @Geohut, can please let me know the what is the problem with my code, i will share plunker, if you have know can please guide me. Thanks

Comment: The guy who posted below fixed it. all you needed to do was add that name. I tested it in your plunker and it works fine. go look at the plunker you made http://plnkr.co/edit/rwrBG7dmziFH1kl89W62?p=info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a `name` attribute on your radio elements to make them a part of a group.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('myRadio', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        template:  '<div class="myClass">\
                      <label>\
                        <input type="radio">\
                        <span></span>\
                      </label>\
                    </div>',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var $radio = element.find('input');
            var $span = element.find('span');

            $radio.attr('name', attrs.group);
            $span.html(attrs.label);
        }
    }
});
```

If more than one input[radio] controls have a same name, they will behave as a group.

You would use this directive like this:

```
<my-radio group="group1" label="Option1"></my-radio>
<my-radio group="group1" label="Option2"></my-radio>
<my-radio group="group1" label="Option2"></my-radio>
```

Comment: Hi @Vinko Bradvica, but it is not working in IE8, do you have any idea, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about IE8? MSDN says it should work for versions after IE7 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534184.aspx

`Windows Internet Explorer 8 and later. In IE8 Standards mode, dynamically setting the name attribute on an input type=radio button correctly applies that button to the same named group. For more information about IE8 mode, see Defining Document Compatibility.`

Comment: Hi @Vinko Bradvica, i am getting error in console log in IE8, Object expected, Do you have any idea, can please help me this one, Thanks

Comment: I don't have access to the IE8 at the moment, I'll check it out in the evening.

Comment: Hi @Vinko Bradvica , i got the issue, Angular js 1.3 is not supporting IE8, now it is working fine. because i am using Angular JS 1.2. . Thanks for your help. Thank you very much. And one more question, Do you have any idea about how to create Custom Directive for Scroll bar in Angular js, Can Please share your Idea, Please....

Answer (score 1):

```
var App = angular.module('myRaido',[]);

App.directive('myRaido',function() {

return {
    restrict : 'E',
    template:  '<div class="myClass"><input type="radio" name='fooRadios'></div>',
    replace:true,
    link:function (scope, element, attrs) {

        element.click(function () {
            console.log("clicked....");
            // body...
        });

        console.log("link should be work as per our expections...", + attrs.valve);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Pranay Dutta, it is not working, can please give any idea, or share plunker please, Thanks

Comment: i just added a name in the template ,i had tried with your plunker it was working f9

Comment: Hi @ Pranay Dutta , can you please share it the plunker

Comment: '<div class="myClass"><input type="radio" name="galaba"></div>' add this to your template thats it